# Running an embedded Powershell script in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I've previously had good success running small powershell scripts in VB.net by launching powershell with a command line, however I tried with a larger script and found it too difficult to fix the code to make it work (For example replacing quotes so vb.net doesn't interpret it)

I had the idea to simply embed a ps1 script file and then run it, that way a separate file isn't needed and I can execute the code easily.

It seemed like this was possible, however I haven't been able to find a way to make it work.

This is the code I'm using below, I have the .ps1 script set to "Embedded Resource" but it seems with my code below, it can't find the file to execute it.

Any ideas? (Disclaimer this isn't my code)

I'm executing it with ExecutePowerShellScript()

```
Private Sub ExecutePowerShellScript()
        Dim scriptResourceName As String = "script.ps1"

        Using ps As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()
            ' Get the embedded PowerShell script as a string.
            Dim assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            Dim script As String = GetEmbeddedResourceText(assembly, scriptResourceName)

            If script IsNot Nothing Then
                ' Add the script text to the PowerShell instance.
                ps.AddScript(script)

                ' Execute the script.
                Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = ps.Invoke()

                ' Check for errors.
                If ps.Streams.Error.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim errorMessage As String = ""
                    For Each errorRecord As ErrorRecord In ps.Streams.Error
                        errorMessage &= errorRecord.ToString() & Environment.NewLine
                    Next
                    MessageBox.Show("Error executing PowerShell script:" & Environment.NewLine & errorMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Else
                    ' Process the results if necessary.
                    ' For example, you can loop through the results and display them.
                    For Each result As PSObject In results
                        ' Process the result as needed.
                        ' For example, you can display it in a TextBox or MessageBox.
                        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString(), "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    Next
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to load.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Function GetEmbeddedResourceText(ByVal assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly, ByVal resourceName As String) As String
        Using stream As System.IO.Stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)
            If stream IsNot Nothing Then
                Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
                    Return reader.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End If
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

I've tried changing the ps1 file to "additional files" as well as trying some variations on code I've found googling.

Comment: Have you debugged?  Are you getting results back from your "GetEmbeddedResourceText" method?

Comment: I'm not getting any useful information. if I remove error checking I get 

'System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentNullException: 'Cannot process'argument because the value of argument "script" is null. Change the value of argument "script" to a non-null value.'

This implies ps.AddScript(script) is empty/null.

It also seems to say "Using ps As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()" of my code is doing nothing.

Comment: Where are you creating this, though?  Something like Visual Studio or VS Code?  If so, you should at least be able to step-debug and check the values of variables, etc. along the way, to find out where it's going astray

Comment: Visual Studio. I think the issue is adding the powershell file to ps.AddScript(script)

I assume my code simply doesn't work, I'm unsure how to debug it any better then that (I'm not particularly knowledgeable)

Comment: Actually it seems I've fixed it. ChatGPT said I needed to add my namespace so I put in         Dim scriptResourceName As String = "mynamespace.script.ps1" The script is now executing.

Comment: Nice one :)  God bless AI - and best of luck to us all!

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution; to benefit future readers I encourage you to post it _as an answer_, which you can [self-accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) after 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add my namespace so I put in

```
Dim scriptResourceName As String = "mynamespace.script.ps1"
```

The script is now executing.